# PHP Conditional Statements for members and non members via Lynda Exercise

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am deeply confused with a Lynda exercise and wondered if anyone could explain this conditional...mess that is jumbling my mind. I am learning PHP and, though I have worked with conditionals before, this exercise is baffling me.

#### BACKGROUND INFO:

The exercise is to display different HTML sections based on if the visitor is a member or non-member. It is a basic challenge, no login page has been created and everything is being hard coded.

#### MY CODE:

Here is a condensed version of part of the exercise I am struggling with:

```
<?php $member = 0 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <?php if (!member) : ?> //CONFUSING PART
    <section class = "non-member">
        <p>This is non-member information</p>
    </section>
    <?php endif ?>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### MY PROBLEM:

What I am baffled with is, we set a variable called $member to 0, which I understand means that the variable is implicitly false due to PHP standards.

The instructor says that by typing $member = 0, we are saying that the visitor is not logged in as a member. Based on this, I am assuming that means that the visitor is a non-member. (Correct me if I am wrong here.)

However, when determining if the "non-member" HTML section will be shown, the instructor typed:

```
<?php if (!$member) : ?>
```

He said that this means that the member is NOT a member, thus a non-member.

#### MY QUESTION:

But how is this true? If $member is initially false (meaning the visitor is a non-member), wouldn't "!" reverse the meaning, thus meaning that the visitor IS a member because now member is true?

If I am reading this completely wrong, please let me know.

Thank you very much to anyone who takes the time to read this and help me out!

Comment: "because now member is true"  The `!` doesn't change the stored value, it changes what is checked by the conditional. It might be helpful for you to review the [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) page of the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the if block is executed if the if condition evaluates to true. So, when `!$member` evaluates to true when `$member = 0`, it shows the "non-member information" text.

```
<?php if (!$member) : ?> //CONFUSING PART
<section class = "non-member">
    <p>This is non-member information</p>
</section>
<?php endif ?>
```

You can think of it as "if not member, do this"

Comment: OH! Thank you very much! I understand now. Have a lovely day!